# My main nav isn't working in IE 8 or below

Tags: css, menu

I think I did a pretty good job on the rest of my site being compatible with earlier versions of IE, but for some reason the main nav at the top gets all messed up in versions of 8 or earlier. Any idea why?

Here's a sample site with just the main nav: http://prayerpond.com/test3.php

The html is here:

```
<body>    
<!--FACEBOOK SDK-->
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '397219657127680',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.3'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <!--END FACEBOOK SDK-->

    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/none-big.png" class="logo_big"></a></div>
    <nav id="mainnav">

    <ul>

    <li><a href="menu.php" class="profilebutton"><img src="images/icon_menu.png" class="navbutton"></a></li>

    <li><a href="my_journal_preanswered_prayers.php" class="journalbutton"><img src="images/icon_journal2.png" class="navbutton"></a></li>

    <li><a href="notifications.php" class="notificationsbutton"><img src="images/icon_notifications2.png" width="22" height="276" class="navbutton"></a></li>

    <li><a href="faith_boosters.php" class="mustreadbutton"><img src="images/icons_must_read2.png" class="navbutton"></a></li>

    </ul>

    </nav></div></div></body>
```

The CSS is here -> http://prayerpond.com/header.css

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out. Because @media doesn't work in CSS 1 or 2 I need to make sure a default version exists outside of a @media condition.